# How to forcefully stop a job in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a web application that creates jobs periodically. This web app is on a server and works fine. If the server crashes and then restarts, the `JobExplorer` shows that job is still running. But in fact that job never stops and I have to stop it myself. To do so, I am trying to use the `JobOperator` and the funny thing is it says it cannot stop a job that is not running.

To get a list of running jobs:

```
for (String jn : jobExplorer.getJobNames())             
   for (JobExecution je : jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jn)) {
        ...
    }
```

To stop a job:

```
try {
    jobOperator.stop(je.getId());
} catch (NoSuchJobExecutionException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (JobExecutionNotRunningException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error message is "JobExecution must be running so that it can be stopped"

Both `je.isRunning()` and `je.isStopping()` return true.

Comment: `But in fact that job never stops and I have to stop it myself`: Can you explain how is the job still running when the server craches? Is the job running in the same JVM as the webapp or in a separate JVM?

Comment: 1. When the server crashes, it restarts automatically. When it boots up again the state of the job is running.
2. They are both on the same JVM

Comment: In this case, you need to update the job status manually in the job repository. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645178/

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I set `e.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED)` and `e.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED)` and then called `jobOperator.stop(je.getId());` Still the status is STOPPING and the job is listed as Running